# Finding and Populating First Row After Filtered Data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a VLOOKUP()/FILTER() to get certain data from another sheet in GoogleSheets. I'd like to add a row of totals in the first row after the results of this formula. But the data will change over time so the 'totals' row will need to be different as the data changes.

An example of what I'm talking about can be seen in this screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Is there a way I can figure out which row to make the totals row using a formula?

For those curious, this is the VLOOKUP/Filter:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!J2:J100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), 1, TRUE), SORT({PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!J2:J100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!H2:H100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), LEFT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!R2:R100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), FIND(" ", PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!R2:R100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 1)), PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!S2:S100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!T2:T100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "first_required", , LEFT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!T2:T100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), FIND(" ", PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!T2:T100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 1))), IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!U2:U100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!U2:U100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), IF (PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!V2:V100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "Sisterhood-Yes", "Yes", "No"), IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!W2:W100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!W2:W100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), IF (PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!X2:X100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "Sisterhood-Yes", "Yes", "No"), IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Y2:Y100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Y2:Y100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), IF (PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Z2:Z100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "Support", "Yes", "No"), IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!AA2:AA100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!AA2:AA100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")))},1,true))
```

Comment: put the totals at the top! :)

Comment: @MattKing A fair solution but that's not what the client wants.

Comment: Edited description and screenshot added.

Comment: Understood.  It'd be significantly easier if you pasted some sampe data into a new tab here called CSV Dump. I made this spreadsheet for this question and it will stay live for 30 days. then view only.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJgJarh3mvMU3mGxRd4rng-5GcHTqb6IUnes70nRdIM/edit

Comment: Done. All data in A2:M10 are populated by the LOOKUP/FILTER formula in A2. As data accumulates in CSV Dump that data will extend further down (to row 20, 50, 100, or however much accumulates). I'd like the totals for columns D, F, H, J and L to appear in the first row under this data.

Comment: I made my attempt in a new tab on your shared sheet called MK.Idea.

Comment: A great solution but missing the sort on last name, first name. I need to assume that they won't come in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in M2 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT({MMULT(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("D2:L"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1), "$", )*1, )*{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D:L))^0); 
 SUM(MMULT(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("D2:L"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1), "$", )*1, )*{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D:L))^0))}, "$#,000.00"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

use in A2:

```
=INDEX({IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!J2:J100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), 1, 1), 
 SORT({PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!J2:J100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 
 PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!H2:H100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 
 LEFT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!R2:R100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), FIND(" ", PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!R2:R100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 1)), 
 PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!S2:S100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!T2:T100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "first_required", , LEFT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!T2:T100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), FIND(" ", PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!T2:T100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")), 1))), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!U2:U100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!U2:U100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!V2:V100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "Sisterhood-Yes", "Yes", "No"), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!W2:W100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!W2:W100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!X2:X100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "Sisterhood-Yes", "Yes", "No"), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Y2:Y100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Y2:Y100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Z2:Z100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "Support", "Yes", "No"), 
 IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!AA2:AA100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!AA2:AA100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")))},1,1)); 
 {{"","","",TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!S2:S100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))), "$#,###0.00"),"",
 SUMPRODUCT(IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!U2:U100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!U2:U100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")))),"",
 SUMPRODUCT(IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!W2:W100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!W2:W100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")))),"",
 SUMPRODUCT(IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Y2:Y100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!Y2:Y100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")))),"",
 SUMPRODUCT(IF(PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!AA2:AA100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>"")) = "$0.00", ,PROPER(FILTER(TRIM('CSV Dump'!AA2:AA100), 'CSV Dump'!H2:H100<>""))))}}})
```

[image]

use in M2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(MMULT(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("D2:L"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1), "$", )*1, )*{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D:L))^0), "$#,##0.00"))
```

Comment: "Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

Comment: Edited description and screenshot added.

Comment: Progress! I used your second formula because the LOOKUP/FILTER is returning several columns. Unfortunately, it's giving an error. "Error
Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But 'Last1' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." I tried to narrow down your SUM formula to add up just one column but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Step in the right direction. It's coming up as 0.00.

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: That's just column M which is easy without an ArrayFormula.  I'm more concerned with columns D, F, H, J and L.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply (I had to get offline). The latest version worked. I didn't know you could pass parameters to INDEX like that. Very interesting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, the totals are already there on the csv.  Can't you just pull them over?

This is the formula I used on the new tab in the [shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJgJarh3mvMU3mGxRd4rng-5GcHTqb6IUnes70nRdIM/edit#gid=1439829112) called MK.Idea

```
=SORT(IFERROR({'CSV Dump'!J2:J,'CSV Dump'!H2:H,INDEX(SPLIT('CSV Dump'!R2:R," "),,1),'CSV Dump'!S2:S,IF(REGEXMATCH('CSV Dump'!T2:T,"_"),,INDEX(SPLIT('CSV Dump'!T2:T," "),,1)),'CSV Dump'!U2:U,MID('CSV Dump'!V2:V,12,3),'CSV Dump'!W2:W,INDEX(SPLIT('CSV Dump'!X2:X,"-"),,2),'CSV Dump'!Y2:Y,LOOKUP(LEFT('CSV Dump'!Z2:Z),{" ","S","Sv"},{"No","Yes",""}),'CSV Dump'!AA2:AA}),1,1,2,1)
```

Comment: @player0 Aren't the totals already in the csv?

Comment: thats indeed true

Comment: A great solution but missing the sort on last name, first name. I need to assume that they won't come in order.

Comment: Understood.  I modified the formula slightly to add a sort.